# How to access a file in Android studio with CIFS

Tags: java, smb, jcifs

I'm writing to code in Android Studio, but I have a problem. I would like to access to exist file on windows shares. Unfornately when I debugging or running the code, it is not working for me. I know that emulator is not same network, but I downloaded ping app and I sent ping, imcp to server what worked. 
I downloaded jcifs-1.3.19.jar then I imported in project, but always stuck at one point.

```
SmbFileInputStream in = new SmbFileInputStream("smb://host/c/My Documents/somefile.txt", auth);
```

This code is from the official site. 
https://www.jcifs.org/src/docs/api/

I've tried it in many ways. Why is not working on emulator?

```
import jcifs.smb.*;
try{
jcifs.Config.setProperty( "jcifs.netbios.wins", "192.168.1.220" );
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domain", "username", "password");
SmbFileInputStream in = new SmbFileInputStream("smb://host/c/My Documents/somefile.txt", auth);
byte[] b = new byte[8192];
int n;
while(( n = in.read( b )) > 0 ) {
    System.out.write( b, 0, n );
}
}
catch(Exeption e)
{}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the target server? 
JCIFS can connect to a server only when the server supports SMBv1. New Windows 10 OSs do not support this protocol.
If you need a Java SMB library that can connect to Windows 10, look for the jNQ library (commercial license).